# I have to remove fiddler generated certs on every start of my tool for HTTPS traffic

Tags: fiddlercore

I have this test tool to try out Fiddler Core:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region AttachEventListeners
        //
        // It is important to understand that FiddlerCore calls event handlers on the
        // session-handling thread.  If you need to properly synchronize to the UI-thread
        // (say, because you're adding the sessions to a list view) you must call .Invoke
        // on a delegate on the window handle.
        //

        // Simply echo notifications to the console.  Because Fiddler.CONFIG.QuietMode=true 
        // by default, we must handle notifying the user ourselves.
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.OnNotification += delegate(object sender, NotificationEventArgs oNEA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("** NotifyUser: " + oNEA.NotifyString);
        };
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Log.OnLogString += delegate(object sender, LogEventArgs oLEA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("** LogString: " + oLEA.LogString);
        };

        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before request for:\t" + oS.fullUrl);
            // In order to enable response tampering, buffering mode must
            // be enabled; this allows FiddlerCore to permit modification of
            // the response in the BeforeResponse handler rather than streaming
            // the response to the client as the response comes in.
            oS.bBufferResponse = false;
        };

        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:HTTP {1} for {2}", oS.id, oS.responseCode, oS.fullUrl);

            // Uncomment the following two statements to decompress/unchunk the
            // HTTP response and subsequently modify any HTTP responses to replace 
            // instances of the word "Microsoft" with "Bayden"
            //oS.utilDecodeResponse(); oS.utilReplaceInResponse("Microsoft", "Bayden");
        };

        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finished session:\t" + oS.fullUrl);
        };

        // Tell the system console to handle CTRL+C by calling our method that
        // gracefully shuts down the FiddlerCore.
        Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(Console_CancelKeyPress);
        #endregion AttachEventListeners

        Console.WriteLine("Starting FiddlerCore...");

        // For the purposes of this demo, we'll forbid connections to HTTPS 
        // sites that use invalid certificates
        Fiddler.CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = true;
        Fiddler.CONFIG.bMITM_HTTPS = true;

        Fiddler.CertMaker.removeFiddlerGeneratedCerts();
        if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.rootCertExists())
        {
            if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.createRootCert())
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to create cert for FiddlerCore.");
            }
        }

        if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.rootCertIsTrusted())
        {
            if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.trustRootCert())
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to install FiddlerCore's cert.");
            }
        }

        // Because we've chosen to decrypt HTTPS traffic, makecert.exe must
        // be present in the Application folder.
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, true, true);
        Console.WriteLine("Hit CTRL+C to end session.");

        // Wait Forever for the user to hit CTRL+C.  
        // BUG BUG: Doesn't properly handle shutdown of Windows, etc.
        Object forever = new Object();
        lock (forever)
        {
            System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(forever);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the user hits CTRL+C, this event fires.  We use this to shut down and unregister our FiddlerCore.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Shutting down...");
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(750);

    }
```

This test tool works, I can capture HTTPS traffic, which I need for my actual tool.
However, the user has to re-install and re-trust the certificate every time the tool starts. If I do not call

```
        Fiddler.CertMaker.removeFiddlerGeneratedCerts();
```

every time, then the tool will not capture HTTPS traffic, and the app I'm monitoring stops working because apparently, the request seems to get intercepted by Fiddler but not routed to the app.

How do I have to set this up so I don't have to remove the fiddler cert every time?

Comment: Are you using the Fiddler `CertMaker.dll` add-on? You'll see a reference in the console if so.

Comment: Yes, I do. Like I wrote, in principle everything works, I can see HTTPS traffic just fine when I start the tool for the first time. It's just that I have to remove the fiddler certs every time the tool starts, or it stops working. http://i.imgur.com/qv3sif3.png

Comment: FWIW, I had the same issue and the solution was to remove certmaker.dll from the project and place makecert.exe into the output foler of the app instead. This lets FiddlerCore create a sticky certificate that works across app launches and allows you to register the cert just once (so it's easy to add an install/uninstall SSL option).

Comment: I posted a solution to this problem here: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jul/29/Using-FiddlerCore-to-capture-HTTP-Requests-with-NET. Basically, after you create the cert you have to capture the cert and private key from Fiddler's Prefs store and store it somewhere persistant. Then next time you want to capture restore the cert/key back into Prefs before you check for the certificate existence. Kinda messy but easy to do. Not sure why Fiddler wouldn't handle this automatically internally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the CertMaker.dll in your application's folder, which means that you're regenerating a new root and new EE certificates every time the application starts.

To prevent this, you need to cache the values of the preferences `fiddler.certmaker.bc.key` and `fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert`

Or remove `CertMaker.dll` and allow the default makecert.exe certificate logic to apply.

Comment: Can you explain "you need to cache the values of the preferences `fiddler.certmaker.bc.key` etc."? What preferences and what keys are you talking about here?

Comment: The named values are preferences, stored in the Fiddler Preferences system (which is covered in the book you have :-). The issue here is that FiddlerCore-based applications do not automatically persist preferences to the registry (like Fiddler does), so you'd need to explicitly store the values of the named preferences (in the registry, on disk, etc) after the CertMaker generates the root and then reload those values into the preferences system when your application next launches.

Comment: Hmmm... Ok, but if you use MakeCert.exe instead of the shipped assemblies then you also get the persisted behavior without having to manually manage the keys. At least that's what I'm seeing and that seems to be the easiest solution unless running on Mono or requiring the special cases where MakeCert certs aren't supported.

Comment: We're getting a bit off-topic here, but yes, MakeCert internally stores all certificates in the Windows certificate store, which itself has some downsides.